# How do I play an old Net Yaroze game?

Tags: emulation, backwards-compatibility, super-bub-contest

I used to really enjoy the game *Super Bub Contest* that was given away on a few Playstation magazine cover discs.

It was a Net Yaroze game, for the original PS.

I no longer have the discs, or a playstation.  How can I play this game again?  Preferably on some modern console (PS2; Wii; Xbox 360) or on a MacBook Pro with Snow Leopard?

EDIT: **I'm not asking for locations of pirated material.  The author has made the game available on his website**

EDIT: Here's a Youtube video to show gameplay.

Comment: Sorry for the tags; I was baffled by which ones to use.

Comment: You might want to checkout [Puzzle Fighter HD](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Puzzle-Fighter-HD/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d8025841086e) for the Xbox 360, or [Puzzle Pirates](http://www.puzzlepirates.com/) where the sword fighting minigame is similar. These go from top to bottom as opposed to bottom to top like the game you linked, but the play style looks very similar. That might be enough to get your fix.

Comment: Did you mean PS2 or PS3?  PS2 can play most Playstation games, but PS3 cannot.

Comment: @bwarner - I have PS2, so all I need is to find the disc?  AWESOME!

Comment: In general yes.  Not all Playstation games work, but it is definitely the first thing you should try.

Comment: @DanBeale I edited out your last sentence since it was a game-rec question, which is off-topic on our site.

Comment: @bwarner Actually the PS3 *can* play all PlayStation 1 games, just not PS2 games (that was possible in *very* early models of the PS3 but is no longer supported). The only caveat is that your PS3 console and your PS1 games must be from the same region.

Comment: @Fallen Woah, I never realized that.  I might just have to try out some Final Fantasy Tactics on PS3 tonight...

Comment: @Wipqozn - although I could just ask an ITG with "It was a game just like *Super Bub Contest*, but not that game" :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Google hit for "Super Bub Contest": http://www.atariage.com/forums/topic/70649-ps1-homebrew-super-bub-contest/ is by the game's author, linking to the homebrew [file](http://www.herbs64.plus.com/files/superbub.zip) and mentioning it should run fine with [epsxe](http://www.epsxe.com/).

[image: screenshot]

<sub>The only thing you still need to acquire is a PAL BIOS file, but due to the legal issues involved with that I won't elaborate on how to obtain that…</sub>

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer links me to an emulator which does not have a version for my OS, and to a forum post mentioning DirextX, which is also not on my system.  I've never used a PSX emulator (on any system) so I'd be really grateful for an answer that includes a link to a good emulator for MacOSX. (I'd set a bounty if I could.) +1 for including info which I should have put into the OP.

Comment: Except I realise that's off topic too.

Comment: Dan, there is an OSX port of ePSXe floating around the net. You could also try using WINE or a dual-boot setup to run ePSXe or using a different emulator with a Mac version such as pcsx, pcsx-reloaded, pcsx2, The Pi, or flarestorm. (DISCLAIMER: I'm not a Mac user so I can't personally vouch for the quality of any of these. Experiment.)

Comment: @Dan I guess if you ask very specifically "Is there a PSX emulator for MacOSX that provides epsxe's functionality?" it _could_ be on-topic. But hey, just try, worst case is it gets closed and you might still get a few pointers as comments...